# Make Underbrace ignore Brackets

Tags: vertical-alignment, brackets, underbrace

I am using under brace to define an important term. The code I'm using generates the following:

[image]

Code:

```
h_n\left[f_X(0)\underbrace{\int_0^{+\infty}K(z)^2dz}_{\equiv\beta} +o_p(1)\right]
```

There is one problem, the brackets extend to allow the beta to fit inside it. I would like to avoid this behavior: brackets extend only enough to fit the integral, but not to fit the underbrace. Instead, I would like to obtain the following:
[image]

Is it possible? How can I generate such outcome?

Thanks for helping! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    h_n\biggl[f_X(0)\underbrace{\int_0^{+\infty}K(z)^2dz}_{\equiv\beta} +o_p(1)\biggr]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's better to avoid the automatic delimiters anyway.  Have a look at the `mathtools` package for better-spaced ones.

Answer (score 2):

I am not advocating this solution, but onw way to solve this issue and still allow for "automatic" resizing is to use `\smash` and an appopriate `\vphantom`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}     
   h_n\left[f_X(0)\vphantom{\int}\smash{\underbrace{\int_0^{+\infty}K(z)^2dz}}_{\equiv\beta} +o_p(1)\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One problem. When using smash inside align with multiple lines, then the next line will collide with the smashed underbrace.

Comment: @mxmlnkn: You can use the optinal parameter to `\\ ` to add some vertical space. For instance, you can use `\\\[1.0ex]` to increase the space between the current line and the subsequent line.